# How to specify the position of nodes with captions in a plot generated by pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

My question is how to specify the position of node in a plot?
Here's a MWE:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=X (\%),
        ylabel=Y (\%),
            legend style={
                draw=none, fill=none, 
                font=\tiny,
                at={(0.5,0.17)},
                anchor=north,
                legend columns=4,
                legend cell align={right},
            },
            xmajorgrids,
        ]
            %CORING (2023)
        \addplot+ [red, mark=square*, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style=
                        {xshift=15pt,yshift=8pt,anchor=east,font=\footnotesize}, ultra thick]
                coordinates {
                    (88.25, 93.07)
                    (78.66, 93.83)
                    (66.60, 94.20)
                    (58.19, 94.42)
                    (40.00, 94.67)
                    (19.16, 94.75)
                    (00.00, 93.96)};
            \legend{
                    Method A
                    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My method. %in terms of accuracy versus FLOPs reduction. 
}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

In this example, my text is overlapped by line.
All nodes's position are set by this:

```
{xshift=15pt,yshift=8pt}
```

But this doesn't work well for all nodes. So I want to modify **the position of each node**.
ChatGPT suggests this but it doesn't work:

> You can modify the position of each node by adding the "node[pos]" option to each coordinate, where "pos" is a value between 0 and 1 that specifies the position of the node along the line connecting the coordinate to its label. For example, to move the node for the first coordinate to the right, you can set "node[pos=0.5]" instead of "nodes near coords" and adjust the "xshift" and "yshift" values accordingly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ChatGPT is a bot that is primarily designed to *chat*. It has no connection to the internet (as far as I know) and therefore its output is only based on what it has been fed during training. Therefore it is (so far at least) limited in giving advice as to how to solve certain problems in TeX. In this case, you want to style a label to a coordinate that has been placed by PGFplots. The option `pos` does not work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the option `coordinate style` to modify the style of certain labels depending on a specific condition (of course you could also set `xshift` or `yshift` for labels at specific coordinates using this mechanism):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=X (\%),
        ylabel=Y (\%),
        legend style={
            draw=none, fill=none, 
            font=\tiny,
            at={(0.5,0.17)},
            anchor=north,
            legend columns=4,
            legend cell align={right},
        },
        xmajorgrids,
    ]
        %CORING (2023)
        \addplot+ [
            red, 
            mark=square*, 
            nodes near coords,
            every node near coord/.append style={
                font=\footnotesize
            }, 
            ultra thick, 
            coordinate style/.condition={x < 10 || x > 40}{
                anchor=west,
            },
            coordinate style/.condition={x > 60}{
                anchor=east,
            }
        ]
        coordinates {
            (88.25, 93.07)
            (78.66, 93.83)
            (66.60, 94.20)
            (58.19, 94.42)
            (40.00, 94.67)
            (19.16, 94.75)
            (00.00, 93.96)
        };
        \legend{
            Method A
        }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]